# Stream writes having multiple identical keys to delta lake

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, delta-lake

I am writing streams to delta lake through spark structured streaming. Each streaming batch contains key - value (also contains timestamp as one column). delta lake doesn't support of update with multiple same keys at source( steaming batch) So I want to update delta lake with only record with latest timestamp. How can I do this ?

This is code snippet I am trying:

```
def upsertToDelta(microBatchOutputDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) {

  println(s"Executing batch $batchId ...")
  microBatchOutputDF.show()

  deltaTable.as("t")
    .merge(
      microBatchOutputDF.as("s"),
      "s.key = t.key")
    .whenMatched().updateAll()
    .whenNotMatched().insertAll()
    .execute()
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can eliminate records having older timestamp from your "microBatchOutputDF" dataframe & keep only record with latest timestamp for given key.

You can use spark's 'reduceByKey' operation & implement custom reduce function as below.

```
def getLatestEvents(input: DataFrame) : RDD[Row] = {
input.rdd.map(x => (x.getAs[String]("key"), x)).reduceByKey(reduceFun).map(_._2) }


def reduceFun(x: Row, y: Row) : Row = {
if (x.getAs[Timestamp]("timestamp").getTime > y.getAs[Timestamp]("timestamp").getTime) x else y }
```

Assumed key is of type string & timestamp of type timestamp. And call "getLatestEvents" for your streaming batch 'microBatchOutputDF'. It ignores older timestamp events & keeps only latest one.

```
val latestRecordsDF = spark.createDataFrame(getLatestEvents(microBatchOutputDF), <schema of DF>)
```

Then call deltalake merge operation on top of 'latestRecordsDF'

Answer (score 1):

In streaming for a microbatch, you might got more than one records for a given key. In order to update it with target table, you have to figure out the latest record for the key in the microbatch. In your case you can use max of timestamp column and the value column to find the latest record and use that one for merge operation.

You can refer this [link](https://docs.delta.io/0.4.0/delta-update.html#write-change-data-into-a-delta-table) for more details on finding the latest record for the given key.

Comment: Will use same approach. Thanks for response.